# Salesforce1 native - How to check if page open in IPAD or in IPhone

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have designed my VisualForce page for Mobile devices(IPhone/Android) as well as IPAD. This is working perfectly on  mobile devices(Iphone/Android) via native SF1 app, mobile browser and IPAD Browser.

**The issue is When I am opening the same page via SF1 native app from IPAD( iOS 7.1)  instead of IPAD View its showing the Mobile view** .  But the same IPAD view is working fine When I am checking it via IPAD browser (Web link and with one/one.app).

Is there any separate way to differentiate the IPhone/Ipad in SF1 app?

The Way I am doing is by checking User-agent from Server end:

```
String userAgent = System.currentPageReference().getHeaders().get('User-Agent');
if (userAgent.contains('iPhone')){
     }
    else if (userAgent.contains('iPad')){
    }  //added comment to allow code formatting
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing baked into the JavaScript sforce library that would help you. The only solution is the user-agent check that you are performing.

Comment: I found the issue here. After debugging the value of userAgent I found that while user is in Salesforce1 native app the value of user-agent changed. For IPAD app user-agent string consist of both "iPhone" and "iPad" along with "Salesforce1". So I need to manipulate my code accordingly.

Comment: @GirishThakur Did you add a user-agent check for S1 in your code? something like this? `return userAgent.contains('Salesforce1')`